# Visiting a website with PhantomJS

Tags: php, phantomjs

I'm trying PhantomJS for the first time, and would like to download a remote site with PHP for SEO purposes. 
I've succeed in downloading the HTML content, however the pages are always "Javascript not enabled" fallbacks. From this I can only conclude that the PhantomJS is visiting the sites without Javascript support.. I've posted the script I'm currently using below, which should be pretty standard. Does anyone know a better way of returning remote HTML content with PhantomJS?

phantom.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var url = system.args[1];

page.open(url,
    function(status){
        if (status !== 'success') {
            phantom.exit(1);
            return;
        } else {
            page.evaluate(
                function() { 
                    return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
                }, 
                function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                }); 
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });
```

index.php

```
$url = escapeshellarg('<some url to test>');
$script = "phantom.js";
$contents = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/phantomjs $script $url");
```

Comment: Perhaps `outerHTML` returns `noscript` elements, which will be present (though invisible) regardless of whether or not you're running with Javascript enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply using `page.content`? Does this work:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var url = system.args[1];

page.open(url,
    function(status){
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log("FAILED:"+status);
            } 
        else{
            console.log(page.content);
            } 
        phantom.exit();
    });
```